# Sync two soundcards

Tags: visual-c++, audio, circular-buffer

I have a program written in C++ that uses RtAudio ( Directsound ) to capture and playback audio at 48kHz samplerate.

The input capture uses a callback option. The callback writes data to a ringbuffer.
The output is a blocking write function in a separate thread that reads from the ringbuffer.

If the input and output devices are the same the audio loops thru perfectly. 
Now I want to get audio from device 1 and playback on device 2. Each device has its own sampleclock set to 48kHz but are not in sync. After a couple of seconds the input and output are out of sync.

Is it possible to sync two independent oudio devices?

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges you face:

1. getting the two devices to start at the same time.
2. getting the two devices to stay in sync.

Both of these tasks are difficult. In the pro audio world, #2 is accomplished with special hardware to sync the word-clocks of multiple devices. It can also be done with a [high quality video signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video-signal_generator). I believe it can also be done with firewire devices, but I'm not sure how that works. In practice, I have used devices with no sync ("wild") and gotten very reasonable sync for up to an hour or two. Depending on what you are trying to do, the sync should not drift more than a few milliseconds over the course of a few minutes. If it does, you can consider your hardware broken (of course, cheap hardware is often broken).

As for #1, I'm not sure this is possible in any reliable sense with directsound. To the extent that it's possible with any audio API, it is difficult at best: both cards have streams that require some time to setup, open and start playing. In general, the solution is to use an API where this time is super low (ASIO, for example). This works reasonably well for applications like video, but I don't know if it really solves the problem in general.

If you really need to solve this problem, you could open both cards, starting to play silence, and use the timing information generated by the cards to establish the delay between putting data into the card and its eventual playback (this will be different for each card and probably each time you run) and use that data to calculate when to start actual playback. I don't know if RTAudio supplies the necessary timing information, but PortAudio does. [This document](http://www.rossbencina.com/static/writings/portaudio_sync_acmc2003.pdf) may help.